# Vue inline CKEDITOR 4 content not updated

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, ckeditor

I'm trying to set the content of an **inline** Vue CKEDITOR 4 component through `v-model`, multiple times. My issue is that this works until the user types text in the editor. Afterwards, anything I pass to the `v-model` is overwritten with what the user typed.

For further clarification, I've defined the steps and code I use:

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Explicitly set editor value 'aaa' through v-model. (non-user change)
2. Type 'bbb' in the editor (so that we have 'aaabbb') (user change)
3. Explicitly set editor value 'ccc' through v-model. (non-user change)

**Expected behaviour:**

- The 'ccc' value is set and shown.

**Actual behaviour:**

1. The 'ccc' value is set in the editor.
2. The 'aaabbb' value is set (overwriting value at 1.) and shown.

**Code:**

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <ckeditor
            v-model="editorData"
            type="inline"
        />
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default class EditorWrapper extends Vue {
    // Vue component property that contains data sent to editor in steps 1. and 3.
    @Prop({ type: String, default: '' })
    externalData!: string;

    // Vue data variable that is bound 2-way to the editor
    editorData: string;

    // watch for changes to the 'externalData' property
    @Watch('externalData')
    onPropertyChange(externalData) {
        // explicitly set the editor text when not changed by the user (steps 1. and 3.)
        this.editorData = externalData;
    }

    // watch for changes to the editor 'v-model' data (user and non-user changes)
    @Watch('editorData')
    onEditorDataChange(data) {
        // this outputs the editor text - 'ccc', then 'aaabbb' - which is wrong
        console.log(data);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a computed setter for your two-way data binding:

https://jsfiddle.net/ellisdod/18ybd6o5/

```
@Prop({ type: String, default: '' })
    value: string;

get _value() {
    return this.value
}

set _value(val) {
    this.$emit('input', val)
}
```

```
<ckeditor
    v-model="_value"
    type="inline"
/>
```

Then you can update in your parent:

```
<editor-wrapper v-model="updatableValue"/>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this solution and the issue still occurs, unfortunately.

Comment: You're right, its because the wrapper wasn't using v-model. Just updated my answer with a working example.